# Tradeability of Option (not underlying) necessary assumption in BSM?

Tags: black-scholes, european-options, trade

Working with the Black Scholes Model to value european Call and Put Options I encountered a question that came up during the valuation of a (european Call) Option, which itself cannot be traded (e.g. management incentive units).

To the best of my knowledge (and understanding) it is of course a crucial assumption in BSM that the underlying stock is tradeable. To my understanding, however, tradeability of the option itself is not needed.

Reason: the idea behind the pricing in BSM is based on the fact that option-payoffs can be reproduced (under market completeness) by a portfolio consisting of units of the risk-free bond and the underlying stock (+ an no arbitrage argument). For this approach, we only need the possibility to buy and sell units of the underlying stock, NOT the option itself. Therefore, I don't see, why the assumption of tradeability of the option should be needed.

Nevertheless, this question came up more than just once and I would be very interested in your thoughts.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think you're right, you don't need the option to be tradeable for BS to work, as long as you can hedge it

Comment: I would not worry too much about the assumptions. None of them is realistic and holds in reality. Yet, it is a useful concept to determine the fair value of an option. On a side remark, If markets are complete, we would not need options (they are meaningless and add no economic value). If markets are inefficient, we may need options. However, if we need the assumption of complete markets to value an option, it is in fact impossible to price them. So either, we do not need them, or cannot price them. That's called the [Hakansson's paradox](https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Hakansson%27s_Paradox).

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

AKdemy: I agree partially. Of course, some of the theoretical assumptions are not satisfied completely in practice/the real world. However, in my opinion, it does make a difference if we talk about a 'hard' assumption (e.g. if the product to be priced itself has to be tradeable). In this sense, if tradeability of the option has to be assumed in the model, it would be difficult to ignore.